# Does drivers are required for USB PostScript printer in linux?

Tags: printer, arch-linux

I am looking for adding a usb printer support in my project with linux kernel 3.0.
and I am stucked that if the postscript printer need a driver or a PPD file is sufficient for it?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the printer supports PostScript natively then a PPD is all you need to tell CUPS what capabilities the printer has.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio,
I was very confused before. I Have been searching for the ans from long time and some sites tells that you will need a driver and couple of saying that you dont need a driver if you have a PPD file.

Comment: What I need to do if GhostScript doesn't have support to my printer?